# Debian package - what constitutes a version change

Tags: debian, apt-get, apt

I've created a .deb package for a hobby project, it's available via my own HTTP server and so can be installed via `apt-get`.

I had been updating the `.deb`, the `.changes` file and regenerating a `Package.gz` and **thought** I'd observed that doing an

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

...would upgrade my software - even though the **version number in the control file remained unchanged**.

I assumed the SHAs in `.changes` and `Package.gz` (or even the date recorded therein) was enough for `apt-get` to recognise they'd been a change and install the new (updated) `.deb`.

However, I was trying to do the same more recently, and `apt-get` repots:

```
my-app is already the newest version (2.1).
```

and not perform an upgrade.

Should I be able to deploy new versions with just a change to SHA and not change the version in the control file? I'd like to be able to deploy updates (whilst in beta for example) without a major version increment.